# how can i decode a plist into data model in swift 5

Tags: json, swift, struct, plist

i have a plist with data that i want to decode into a model in swift 5
all attempts at doing this have failed so any help will be appreciated.
i assume my model is wrongly configured, or perhaps some other issue i don't understand.

there's no error thrown, but when i try to access any value, or print out any data, there is none.

the path to the plist file is fine, the issue is with the line below or it failing to decode into the model as I've defined it.

```
   let data = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(COPickerData.self, from: xml)
```

this is my model:

```
struct COPickerData: Codable{
var Material:String?
var Sizes:String?
var Detail: CoPickerDetail?
}

struct CoPickerDetail: Codable {
var min, wallmin, wallstd, max: String?
var std, wallmax, mouldid: String?
}
```

this is my plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>1. Nat</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1. 36</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>max</key>
                <string>500</string>
                <key>min</key>
                <string>75</string>
                <key>mouldid</key>
                <string>38</string>
                <key>std</key>
                <string>150</string>
                <key>wallmax</key>
                <string>7.5</string>
                <key>wallmin</key>
                <string>3.5</string>
                <key>wallstd</key>
                <string>5</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>2. 38</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>max</key>
                <string>500</string>
                <key>min</key>
                <string>75</string>
                <key>mouldid</key>
                <string>40</string>
                <key>std</key>
                <string>150</string>
                <key>wallmax</key>
                <string>7.5</string>
                <key>wallmin</key>
                <string>3.5</string>
                <key>wallstd</key>
                <string>5</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>2. GF30</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1. 36</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>max</key>
                <string>500</string>
                <key>min</key>
                <string>75</string>
                <key>mouldid</key>
                <string>38</string>
                <key>std</key>
                <string>150</string>
                <key>wallmax</key>
                <string>7.5</string>
                <key>wallmin</key>
                <string>3.5</string>
                <key>wallstd</key>
                <string>5</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>2. 38</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>max</key>
                <string>500</string>
                <key>min</key>
                <string>75</string>
                <key>mouldid</key>
                <string>40</string>
                <key>std</key>
                <string>150</string>
                <key>wallmax</key>
                <string>7.5</string>
                <key>wallmin</key>
                <string>3.5</string>
                <key>wallstd</key>
                <string>5</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: *there's no error thrown* because **you** ignore it with `try?`. Add a `do - catch` block, remove the question mark and `print` the error. Basically there are no keys `Material`, `Sizes` and `Detail` in the plist. You have to use CodingKeys anyway because in a struct a member name must start with a letter (or an underscore). A key like `2. 38` is not allowed.

Comment: Hi vadian thanks for responding can you offer some code snippets to explain what you mean please - I’m only just delving into swift so far from experienced.thanks

Comment: Here are some: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-swift-codable-with-property-lists/ or here: https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swift-tutorials/working-with-property-lists-in-swift-part-one/

Comment: I’ve read through these blogs and they don’t really help me understand the structure of the data model I need